# How to run command line inside a django view?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, npm, command-line

**[Context]**

I have a  file upload operation in my Django application (on ubuntu server), I have to execute an operation after the user uploaded the file. The tool for that is only available as a npm package (accessible via command line).

1. What is the recommended solution for this?

Comment: Too broad! Let me give you some idea. Dispatch job to `child-process`. Because it is gonna be time consuming task

Comment: Yea use celery and raven

Answer (score 0):

Django is is python webframework. So you can use any of the module provided by python. However give a try to [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. This module is a preferred way of running other programs with Python. Take a look.

`import subprocess
 print(subprocess.check_output(['ls','-l']))`